# Exe file made with pyinstaller write to file dynamically

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have a scraper which reads credentials from `credentials.txt`. I've made GUI app with `pyqt5` and made an executable with `pyinstaller` to run the app. The app has a username and password fields which when an `apply` button is clicked it writes to the `credentials.txt` and from there the scraper takes the needed information. Unfortunately, the credentials are changed/refreshed after the GUI app is relaunched. My question is, is there anyway the app to write to the .txt file and apply the changes without the need to relaunch the app. I understand that my description may not be full, so I would gladly give more information if required.

The app window looks like this:

[image]

I have used the same principle with the `Course Page Link` field, thus I require my app to be open and not relaunched in order to download sequentially multiple courses.

Comment: Where are you writing the file? If you need persistent data, use [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html).

Comment: It doesn't have problem with persisting data, I just want to be able to click the apply button and already have the new data updated, however it is updated only when I close and open again the app and not runtime.

Comment: Then your question is unclear. Please take your time to [edit] it and try to explain better what you want to do.

Comment: create a [example]